# Error 404 Forbidden in simple machines SMF

Tags: php

Please I need your help on this. I have a site hosted using SMF, when I try login, this is the error I see. Please what may be the cause? Below is the error that display as I login in.

> Forbidden
>
> You don't have permission to access /government/index.php on this server.
>
> Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Answer (score 0):

An error telling you that you aren't allowed to use this file means, that you need to change the permissions of this file, because the web service can not open it. Make sure you have all necessary permissions.

You can change permissions on a Linux based system with chmod.